# Button dropdown not working properly in Reactstrap | React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, reactstrap

I'm working on a react project, using [Button Dropdown](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/button-dropdown/) component of [Reactstap](https://reactstrap.github.io/).

Dropdown working correctly but when it opens up, it overlaps the content in the website (in my case it is just a [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) in which I'm displaying some data.)

**My problem is while overlapping the content, it partially allows us to interact with the table beneath it** (As shown in the image it allows to resize column instead of selecting that item). It prevents that click behavior on the dropdown icon.

[image]

Kindly help me.

Here is my code

```
render() {

  return (
    <ContentWrapper>
      <div className="content-heading">
        Users
        <div className="header-actions">
          <i className="fas fa-search fa-xs header-action mt-2 neutral5-color" />
          <Input
            id="serach"
            name="name"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ search: event.target.value })}
            className="header-action"
          />
          <Button
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.toggleModal}
            className="header-action">
            Add User
          </Button>

          <ButtonDropdown color="primary" isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={() => {this.setState({dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen})}}>
            <DropdownToggle caret>
              Filter (All)
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('all')}>All</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('user')}>User</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('super user')}>Super user</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('super admin')}>Super Admin</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </ButtonDropdown>

          <AddUser
             toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
             fields={this.state}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="section-content-wrapper flex-column">
        <Card className="card-default user-card-height">
          <CardBody>
            <ReactTable
              data={users}
              columns={this.columns}
              noDataText={"Didn't find any user."}
              defaultPageSize={DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE_IN_TABLE}
              showPageSizeOptions={false}
              PaginationComponent={CustomPagination}
              minRows={0}
              sortable={false}
              loading={is_loading}
              onPageChange={page =>
                document.getElementsByClassName('rt-tbody')[0].scrollTop = 0
              }
            />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </ContentWrapper>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about Reactstap itself but the solution is that You need to make sure that the dropdown z-index is higher than the table and anything in the background that you want to be behind this dropdown menu.

Comment: How to set `z-index` to the max? P.S. I'm new to frontend development.

Comment: @JayPatel you dont have to set z-index to the max, it just has to be higher than values in the background, you can play with the values itself. i would suggest first use the chrome dev tools to locate the element then try a higher z-index on the element, after that set that value to that element from React

Comment: I set the `z-index` of table to 0 and it worked. Thanks